# How to get Google+ Auto-backup link to a video?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, links, video

If you have enabled Google+ Auto-backup on your phone, then pictures and videos are uploaded to Google+. The problem is that there are no links to the videos, and if you try to download and video, and then upload it to your YouTube account, then it gets rejected because of duplicate.

The video in Google+ Auto-backup is played back with a modified Youtube player, where I can not find any way to get the URL for the video.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to get the link to the video, so I can share it over email to people that don't have Google+?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want to have a link from a video that was automatically backed up, you have to share it first on Google+. That'll give you a link you can use.

If you want to upload the video to YouTube, you can either upload it directly to YouTube (by having a local copy), or you can import the video directly to YouTube according to [the tutorial here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/youtube/O0bzeAubIss).